# TemplateDoesNotExist when using as_view()

Tags: python, django, view

I receive:

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /skills2/
portfolio/skill_list.html
```

when access http://127.0.0.1:8000/skills2/

**mysite/mysite/urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()
from portfolio.views import skills, experience, index, v_index, SkillsView
from django.conf.urls import include, url
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^skills2/$', SkillsView.as_view(), name='skills'),]
```

**mysite/portfolio/models.py**

```
from django.db import models
class Skill(models.Model):
    publish_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')
    description = models.TextField(default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**mysite/portfolio/views.py**

```
from .models import Skill, Experience
class SkillsView(generic.ListView):
    model = Skill
```

**mysite/portfolio/templates/index2.html**

```
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}

{% block content %}
<h1>Portf site</h1>

  <p>Welcome to <em>My Site</em>, a very basic Django website</p>

<h2>Dynamic content</h2>

  <p>The site has the following record counts:</p>
  <ul>
    <li><strong>Skills:</strong> {{ num_skills }}</li>
    <li><strong>Exp:</strong> {{ num_experience }}</li>
  </ul>

{% load static %}
<img src="{% static 'oh_i_ah.jpg' %}" alt="My image" style="width:640px;height:473px;"/>

{% endblock %}
```

**mysite/portfolio/templates/base_generic.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

  {% block title %}<title>My portfolio web-site</title>{% endblock %}
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Add additional CSS in static file -->
  {% load static %}
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/styles.css' %}">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-2">
      {% block sidebar %}
      <ul class="sidebar-nav">
          <li><a href="{% url 'v_index' %}">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="{% url 'skills' %}">All skills</a></li>
          <li><a href="{% url 'exp' %}">All experience</a></li>
      </ul>
     {% endblock %}
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-10 ">
      {% block content %}{% endblock %}
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**mysite/portfolio/skills_list.html**

```
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Skill List</h1>

    {% if item_list %}
    <ul>

      {% for item in item_list %}
      <li>
        <a href="{{ items.get_absolute_url }}">{{ items.name }}</a>
      </li>
      {% endfor %}

    </ul>
    {% else %}
      <p>There are no skill in the library.</p>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

**settings.py**

```
"""
Django settings for mysite project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.10.6.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '71o%ek_%m5fg6ts(c_9_nj+m6eaf*&+jqgq^3ghih%26+opa12'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'portfolio',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'
# import os

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC +3'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),)
# STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_root')
```

So it seems to be looking for portfolio/skill_list.html which exists.

Comment: can u add your setting file ?

Comment: also would you please explain what the error means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'..', 'templates')],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
```

]

Comment: path has been changed to: [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '..', 'templates')]. The issue still remains

Comment: url(r'^skills2/$', SkillsView.as_view(template_name=<ADD_YOUR_TEMPLATE_PATH>), name='skills'),

Answer (score 1):

Django looks in the `templates` directory for each app. Therefore your `portfolio/skill_list.html` template should be in `mysite/portfolio/templates/portfolio/skill_list.html`.

Comment: has been copied: mysite/mysite/portfolio/templates/portfolio/skills_list.html. The error is still the same

Comment: Your question shows `skills_list.html` with an s, but the error message is `skill_list.html` without an s. Make sure it is named correctly.